# Tell heroku to listen to specific port

Tags: heroku, client-server, port

I have downloaded an sdk of inet pdfc (pdf comparison software) and i am trying to 
set it remotely. Right now, i am trying to use trial version and find out if it can be used remotely or not.

The sdk has a main jar called PDFC.jar. The jar internally launches an embedded server and open a connection at localhost:9900. I deployed all the necessary jars in heroku and when i open the jar in heroku, the aplication opens and gives a message:

> Waiting for plain client requests on port 9900.

Similarly, after some time heroku also sends a message,

> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Now, i cannot explicitly set the application to launch at certain port.
So, i am trying to set heroku to use port 9900.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any suggestion on solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very specific question you should send this to the support team of the product: pdfc@inetsoftware.de